# Elasticsearch multi_field type search and sort issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having an issue with `multi_field` mapping type in one of my indexes and I am not sure what the issue is. I use a very similar mapping in another index and I don't have these issues. ES version is 90.12

I have set this up I have a mapping that looks like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 10,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "production": {
      "properties": {
        "production_title": {
          "type": "multi_field",
          "fields": {
            "production_title_edgengram": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "analyzed",
              "index_analyzer": "autocomplete_index",
              "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
            },
            "production_title": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `.yml` looks like this:

```
index:
  mapper:
    dynamic: true
  analysis:
    analyzer:
      autocomplete_index:
        tokenizer: keyword
        filter: ["lowercase", "autocomplete_ngram"]
      autocomplete_search:
        tokenizer: keyword
        filter: lowercase
      ngram_index:
        tokenizer: keyword
        filter: ["ngram_filter"]
      ngram_search:
        tokenizer: keyword
        filter: lowercase
    filter:
      autocomplete_ngram:
        type: edgeNGram
        min_gram: 1
        max_gram: 15
        side: front
      ngram_filter:
        type: nGram
        min_gram: 2
        max_gram: 8
```

So doing this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/productionindex/production/_search' -d '{
  "sort": [
    {
      "production_title": "asc"
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}'
```

and

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/productionindex/production/_search' -d '{
  "sort": [
    {
      "production_title": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}'
```

I end up with the exact same result somewhere in the middle of the alphabet:

```
"production_title": "IL, 'Hoodoo Love'"
```

However, if I do this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "production_title": "IL, 'Hoodoo Love'"
    }
  }
}
```

I get zero results.

Furthermore, if I do this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "production_title_edgengram": "Il"
    }
  }
}
```

I also get zero results.

If I don't use `multi_field` and I separate them out, I can then search on them fine, (term and autocomplete) but I still can't sort.

While indexing I am only sending `production_title` when indexing `multi_field`.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Below please find the explain (last result only for brevity)

```
{
  "_shard": 6,
  "_node": "j-D2SYPCT0qZt1lD1RcKOg",
  "_index": "productionindex",
  "_type": "production",
  "_id": "casting_call.productiondatetime.689",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "venue_state": "WA",
    "updated_date": "2014-03-10T12:08:13.927273",
    "django_id": 689,
    "production_types": [
      69,
      87,
      89
    ],
    "production_title": "WA, 'Footloose'"
  },
  "sort": [
    null
  ],
  "_explanation": {
    "value": 1.0,
    "description": "ConstantScore(cache(_type:audition)), product of:",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 1.0,
        "description": "boost"
      },
      {
        "value": 1.0,
        "description": "queryNorm"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

from this curl:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/productionindex/production/_search?pretty=true&explain=true' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "production_title": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Comment: This all seems to work.  See https://gist.github.com/clintongormley/9483845. While you've presented a lot of useful information, formatting it as something that we can run from beginning to end (as in my gist example) makes it easier to spot where you've gone wrong.

Comment: @DrTech Here is a gist that fails: https://gist.github.com/eire1130/eedf88c0b9fce6362746

Comment: The problem is your badly formatted geopoint:  

    "venue_location": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 27.4011673,
            "lon": -82.3994214
        }
    },

The extra `location` shouldn't be there.  However, ES should complain instead of just ignoring the fields following that bad geopoint. I've opened an issue: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5390

Comment: @DrTech Great thank you. Sort still seems wonky based on a match_all (first results begin with an O for desc and an H for asc. There are A's and V's in the index. I would assume that it should be sorting by alpha?

Comment: Your gist is gone now, but simplify the problem - makes it easier to reason about it. Also the value that is sorted on is returned in the `sort` parameter, which should help you to figure it out.